What is the theological difference between anthropomorphism and theanthropism?
I understand from this article
that anthropomorphism is the process of assigning human characteristics to God:

Anthropic means “relating to human beings or their existence.”  The word anthropomorphism comes from two Greek words, anthropos, meaning “man,” and morphe, meaning “form.” In theological terms, anthropomorphism is the process of assigning human characteristics to God. Human traits and actions are ascribed to the Creator. We read of God’s actions, emotions, and appearance in human terms, or at least in words we normally accept and associate with humans.

Then I came across the word theanthropism.  My 1979 Collins English Dictionary said:

Theanthropism – ascription of human traits or characteristics to God. ‘Theol’ – doctrine of hypostatic union of divine and human natures in the person of Christ.

How is theanthropism theologically different from anthropomorphism?  Does it relate to the union of the divine and human natures in Christ?

Anthropomorphism has a much wider usage than just theology - Hello Kitty is anthropomorphic for example. I haven't ever seen "theanthropism" before, but from that short description it seems synonomous.

https://english.stackexchange.com/ might be better for word differences

isn't Theanthropism just [anthropomorphism] In theological terms. anthropic is general term that can be used with any non human (animals, plants, etc) and Theanthropism is specifically about God?

@depperm  The English site would not delve into the theological significance of how those words differ. This is a Christianity Q because it asks about the doctrine of the hypostatic union of divine and human natures in the person of Christ. Answers would need to deal with the doctrine of the hypostatic union, surely? Those who do not believe in such a thing might not be best placed to answer, as the tags indicate.

@curiousdannii - I came across the word 'theanthropism' in a book by A.W. Tozer on the subject of Worship.  He said the word was used by old theologians which may explain why I'm struggling to find a Christian definition.

What is the theological difference between anthropomorphism and theanthropism?
First of all, what is anthropomorphism and theanthropism and how are they different?

Anthropomorphism is the attribution of human traits, emotions, or intentions to non-human entities. It is considered to be an innate tendency of human psychology. Personification is the related attribution of human form and characteristics to abstract concepts such as nations, emotions, and natural forces, such as seasons and weather. Both have ancient roots as storytelling and artistic devices, and most cultures have traditional fables with anthropomorphized animals as characters. People have also routinely attributed human emotions and behavioral traits to wild as well as domesticated animals.


Theanthropism
1.: A state of being God and man
especially: the union of the divine and human natures in Christ.

a): The ascription of human attributes to the Deity, or to a polytheistic deity: Anthropomorphism.



b): Belief in the incarnation of deity in human form or in the divinity of a mortal.

Theanthropism is clearly a term used to express the two natures of Christ in the person of Jesus. Christ has two natures, one human and the other divine.
Anthropomorphism on the other hand may be used in the attribution of human traits, emotions, or intentions to non-human entities, in this case to God, the Trinity, the Holy Spirit or God the Father. For example we Could be speaking of God the Father having eyes through which he see his whole creation. Well, obviously God the Father being a spiritual being, does not have a body and thus does not possess eyes though which he can see his creation. Ergo, anthropomorphism is used as a metaphor to convey a certain meaning to us, who understand things better in a concept of making a concept more easier to understand for our human nature! After all we live in a physical world.
